# how to retrieve values from a table which are stored in a colomn

Tags: php, mysql

How can I retrieve the values from a table which I stored in a column using a text box by comma          separated.
Like:

Enter Member Names: [raj, ram, john, mop]

It has been stored in a column as this is [raj, ram, john, mop]; on site I want it in a select option:

```
Select Member: 
 <option>raj</option>
 <option>ram</option>
 <option>john</option>
 <option>jonh</option>
```

Option will be so on, how to resolve it. any query to retrieve this type of data

Comment: It is best to change your table design and store all values seperately.

Comment: SELECT colname FROM tablename. php str_split. Did you actually try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you work like this

```
   $query=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from table_name"));
  $exp=explode(",",$query['col_name']);

  foreach($each as $exp)
 {
 ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $each[0];?>"><?php echo $each[0];?></option>
 <option value="<?php echo $each[1];?>"><?php echo $each[1];?></option>
 <option value="<?php echo $each[2];?>"><?php echo $each[2];?></option>
 <option value="<?php echo $each[4];?>"><?php echo $each[3];?></option>
 <?php
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT member_name FROM users";
// after getting the result 

$resultArray = explode(",",$ft['members']); // $ft['members'] is "raj, ram, john, mop"

foreach($resultArray as $value) {
 echo $value;
 echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: i tried this 
     <?php 
     $query1=mysql_query("select * from golf_details");
     while($ft=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
     {
      echo $ft['members'];

      $resultArray = explode(",",$result);

      foreach($resultArray as $value) {
      echo $value;
      echo "<br>"; 
     }
     }
     ?>

one more thing i am talking about one colomn, like i want the list of comma saprated values from one colomn

Comment: i answered please check, with pic and more description

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
<?php echo '<select name="name">';

$list = explode(',', $value);    
foreach ($list as $item)
{
    echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $item . '</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Hey, please check my answer which i have posted, i want a list of values from a single long string like: raj,suthar,stack,over....so i want the list of four values [1].raj [2]. suthar [3].stack, [4], stack